# Translating recursion with globals to iteration using stack

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, recursion, stack

How would you translate a recursive function that uses global variables to an iterative one?

One example of this is using depth-first search where I want to keep track of the path:

```
path = []

function dfs(node)
    node.visited = true
    path.append(node)

    if node == goal
        print path
        stop;

    for child in node.children
        if !child.visited
            dfs(child)

    path.pop()
```

How would I do this using iteration and a stack?

Comment: There is an C# example that may help you in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Comment: Do you know how to do it for a function that does not use globals?

Comment: So where exactly the methid you know is breaking down?

Comment: @n.m: It breaks down when you're trying to backtrack through the states. I could make `path` a non-global variable, but that would incur a very large overhead.

Comment: I can't see how it causes to large overhead? e.g rio's answer doesn't used too many memory or other overheads.

Comment: I can't se **how** it breaks down. You backtrack (by explicitly popping some state from a stack) and the global state becomes different from the recursive case (which backtracks by invisibly popping some state from the call stack)... where and how does it happen? Can you show an example?

Comment: @n.m: In the example I gave, I've had problems figuring out how to do the `path.pop()` iteratively. Could you show an example of how you would implement the recursive function I gave iteratively?

Comment: Any recursive function can be transformed to iterative in the same way. It is a mechanical process. Make a stack that contains the local state. Transform recursive calls to `push` operations on this stack. Transform `return`s to `pop` operations on this stack. You need to reposition some code, or to wrap some code in `if`s and add bool flags, to achieve the original order of execution. You also need to transform the `for` loop to a `while` loop, so that you don't have state that you cannot manipulate (current child in this case). Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you could extend the Node class, it will be like below.

```
function iterative_dfs(start_node)
    start_node.next = null
    start_node.visited = true

    stack = []
    stack.push(start_node)

    while !stack.empty?
        node = stack.pop

        if node == goal
            path = []
            while node
                path.push(node)
                node = node.next
            path.reverse
            print path
            stop;

        for child in node.children
            if !child.visited
                child.next = node
                child.visited = true
                stack.push(child)
```

Also, your code has a bug. You should pop the node if you couldn't find the goal.

```
function dfs(node)
    node.visited = true
    path.append(node)

    if node == goal
        print path
        stop;

    for child in node.children
        if !child.visited
            dfs(child)

    path.pop    # You need this
```